# find rectangles in image, preferably with skimage

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, scikit-image

I have an [Image](https://postimg.org/image/tnutzqvml/) obtained from a camera (inner part of my VW T5 Van). I would like to know how accurately I can reproduce the shapes. I corrected for lens distortion using lensfun and gimp. I would like to quantify the remaining distortions by utilizing the rectangular features. I can detect the rectangles using `match_template` but I do not know how to detect the rectangles.

In the end I would like to label them and measure the width and length. In order to visualize the centers better I tried to locate the centers but this is not as straightforward as I thought because a simple threshold counts the same spots several times. How can I find the centers of all detected rectangles ?

Can this be done with skimage ? Or should I use opencv ?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import ndimage as ndi
from scipy.ndimage.filters import maximum_filter
from scipy.ndimage import center_of_mass
from skimage.color import rgb2grey
from skimage.feature import match_template
from skimage import feature, io
from skimage import img_as_float
%matplotlib inline

image = io.imread('../lensfun_cut.JPG')
imgray = rgb2grey(image)

    template = imgray[1365:1390,445:470]
    result = match_template(imgray, template)

    # 
    hit = np.where(result>0.90)
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(ncols=1,figsize=(8,8))
    ax.imshow(result,cmap=plt.cm.spectral)

    # loop over the detected regions and draw a circe around them
    for i in range(len(hit[0])):
        rect = plt.Circle((hit[1][i],hit[0][i]), 20,linewidth=1, edgecolor='r', facecolor='none')
        ax.add_patch(rect)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the opencv solution quicker at hand, sorry.

- I'd recommend to use an adaptive threshold to properly segment rectangles from backround with varying illumination
- drawcontours allow you to draw contours
- I have given you a list of contour features and a link to definitions, this may help you to select the proper rectangles
- I am using some contour features to select teh appropriate blobs, you may want to fine tune this.

Result looks that way:

[image]

And here is the code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread('lensfun_cut.jpg',0)

# Adaptive threshold to detect rectangles independent from background illumination
th3 = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(img,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C,cv2.THRESH_BINARY,31,5)

# Detect contours
_, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours( th3.copy(), cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

# Draw contours
h, w = th3.shape[:2]
vis = np.zeros((h, w, 3), np.uint8)
cv2.drawContours( vis, contours, -1, (128,255,255), 3)

# Print Features of each contour and select some contours
contours2=[]
for i, cnt in enumerate(contours):
    cnt=contours[i]
    M = cv2.moments(cnt)

    if M['m00'] != 0:
        # for definition of features cf http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d1/d32/tutorial_py_contour_properties.html#gsc.tab=0
        cx = int(M['m10']/M['m00'])
        cy = int(M['m01']/M['m00'])
        area = cv2.contourArea(cnt)
        x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
        aspect_ratio = float(w)/h
        rect_area = w*h
        extent = float(area)/rect_area        

        print i, cx, cy, area, aspect_ratio, rect_area, extent

        if area < 80 and area > 10:
            contours2.append(cnt)

#Draw selected contours
h, w = th3.shape[:2]
vis2 = np.zeros((h, w, 3), np.uint8)
cv2.drawContours( vis2, contours2, -1, (128,255,255), 3)

titles = ['Original Image', 'Adaptive Gaussian Thresholding', 'Contours', 'Selected Contours']
images = [img, th3, vis, vis2]
for i in xrange(4):
    plt.subplot(2,2,i+1),plt.imshow(images[i],'gray')
    plt.title(titles[i])
    plt.xticks([]),plt.yticks([])
plt.show()
```

Comment: interesting solution. Especially the method to remove the border. I will give it a try. Do you think a method like sobel might introduce less noise ?

Comment: I'd probably not try to remove noise with image preprocessing but wait for teh contour level. Your rectangles hav an almost perfect shape, but are very small, each preprocessing runs the danger of deteriorating shape. However, shape will be your choice when selecting rectangle shape types from other blobs, and I think you can do this by simply using contour featurs as shown above, though you may have to play with parameters a little. The next approach I'd choose is to detect the grid of rectangles and look for blobs only at the position of the grid crosses.